# Lo Yilbash: necklaces and rings

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, men-male, jewelry, lo-yilbash

Is there are prohibition for men to wear rings, necklaces, earrings, bracelets or anything of the kind or would that go against the prohibition of "Lo Yilbash Gever Simlat Isha — a man shall not wear the clothes of a woman"? Sources are appreciated more than logic.

Comment: What about earrings, I wonder?

Comment: @jake I like,edited.

Comment: Logic is officially appreciated :)

Comment: http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/766156/Rabbi_Aryeh_Lebowitz/Ten_Minute_Halacha_-_Red_Bendels

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1199

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28926/2091

Comment: וְלֹא בְטַבַּעַת שֶׁאֵין עָלֶיהָ חוֹתָם,

shabbath 6 -->לֹא תֵצֵא אִשָּׁה בְמַחַט הַנְּקוּבָה, וְלֹא בְטַבַּעַת שֶׁיֵּשׁ עָלֶיהָ חוֹתָם

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I appreciate the desire for sources, you must understand that the issur of lo yilbash is much more subjective than many or most other halachos. Most likely you're familiar with opinions which prohibit from looking in mirrors, but that isn't necessarily the practice today when it is common for males to pay attention to their appearance in the mirror.

I would suggest that many of the major poskim who we would typically turn to for written responsa travel in circles where such jewelry would be excessive and seem effeminate. Obviously someone who is asking such a pesak is presumably involved in circles where it is much more common, whether at work or so forth. I would suggest that there are certainly reasons to argue either way based on the subjective nature of the issur so the only real option is to consult a Rav who is familiar with the social circumstances.

(If there are published teshuvos which rule stringently I would be very uncomfortable to be lenient even if the circumstances have changed, at least because it is still not all that common in the general public in my experience and observation.)

Comment: +1 I like the answer. BTW Hacham Ovadia allows looking in mirrors nowadays.

Comment: Re "the issur of lo yilbash is much more subjective than many or most other halachos": I suppose that's built into the _isur_, though: whatever's considered a _simlas isha_ is what _lo yilbash gever_, and that varies by time and location. So it's not subjective in the usual sense (a matter of personal opinion or preference) so much as subjective precisely in the sense that it fluctuates with culture. I assume that's what you meant?

Comment: msh20, exactly.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17124/1601

Comment: @msh210 In most of the orthodox world I would imagine men don't wear rings, however in much of the world at large and even among orthodox jews there are men that wear rings. So how is this dealt with if a person is part of a "more charedi" community.

Comment: @Yehoshua, beats me. Formulate a good question and [ask it](/questions/ask).