# Does Nivul Peh apply to writing?

Tags: halacha, language, speech-talking, writing-printing

Is it considered Nivul Peh if one writes an inappropriate phrase? (For example, if one is writing a book with fictional dialogue, or a dictionary of slang terms.)

Comment: Why not just ask simpler - Is it nivul peh to ask a Rov if the phrase is nivul peh?

Comment: That's a different question. I guess I want to know whether nivul peh in writing is nivul peh. Perhaps this should be split into two questions.

Comment: @Malper, I think a better test case that would address that concern is whether one must refrain from writing out such terms when there is a legitimate need for transcribing actual conversations where they are used.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu Good point. I'll split this into two questions.

Comment: I would assume it does,the issur is to even listen to it.The issur seems to come from the demoralization that nivul peh causes,however speech in Judaism is very powerful,so could be a different level,see the discussion of speaking or writing Torah to be yotzai Talmud Torah

Comment: See: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/75346/8775 which indicates that nivvul peh is not an actual prohibition. Rather, it is an outgrowth of standard norms of behaviour. Accordingly, nivvul peh presumably doesn't have technical definitions; rather, the point is to simply speak appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to relationships the Sefarim do not call the body parts by their name. It is called אותו מקום. This would indicate to me that it is inappropriate to write Nivul Pe. I would say that it can cause one to read it out loud and say it.

Comment: That's due to considerations of *lashon n'kiya* (i.e. using particularly refined language). *Nivul peh* is more extreme than using language that is simply not *lashon n'kiya*.

Comment: @Fred Since *nivul peh* is more extreme than using language that is simply not *lashon n'kiya* and Chazal were careful to use *lashon n'kiya*, it follows kal vochomer that it is inappropriate to write *Nivul Pe*.

Comment: Is it nivul peh to refer (in speech) to the body parts by their respective "normal" names?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I didn't say it was appropriate, but it might be on the same level as writing non-*lashon n'kiya*, rather than equivalent to speaking *nivul peh*.