# Does halacha forbid profanity?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, language

This is obviously just for research sake. But what does halacha say about using profanity. Is it forbidden. Can it be used in times of emphasis and where is the line drawn for what is considered profanity.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18222/source-for-the-prohibition-against-nivul-peh-foul-mouth

Comment: @Shokhet wouldnt say its a duplicate. Nivul Peh is forbidden. But Rashi (to I think Shabbos 33) clearly states what the parameters for that are. However a lot of language used in our day and age doesnt fit those parameters. That is why I am asking.

Comment: @msh I'm don't quite see why this is a dupe.

Comment: @DoubleAA "Is there a portion of Talmud that deals with the specifics?" asks the other. Meaning — practical specifics (since it then proceeds to explain why the practice is unclear). And indeed jake's answer there answers that part of the question. That said, I wouldn't close this today.

Comment: @msh210 That'd be specifics of "Lashon Naki". Is that the [only] issue with profanity? Moreover the Talmud's saying something and the Halakha saying something aren't always identical.

Comment: @DoubleAA, no, there's also _bitul z'man_.

Comment: It's probably worth reopening this question. armoose, would you like it reopened?

Comment: @msh210 If it is reopened it might be worth considering redirecting the [duplicate to the newer question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78533/759).