# Is there a Halachic problem with cursing?

Tags: halacha, speech-talking, maseches-shabbos

Our tradition mentions the serious transgression of "nivul peh" and the punishments that Hashem brings down on the world due to this sin (Shabbos 33a, Vayikra Rabba 24-7).

What I want to know is if this applies to the regular American curse words such as the F-word, the S-word and similar words. It would seem from some of the sources that it only applies to discussing private sexual matters in a non-respectful way. Would this mean that the F-word is more problematic than the S-word because the former has a sexual connotation, while the latter doesn't? Or maybe these words are not included at all if not used in a sexual connotation in the wrong way? What about words like the B-word? I understand that we shouldn't be using these words at all. I'm just wondering if it's included in the severe sin of "nivul peh" that Chazal discuss.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43433/759

Comment: `Our tradition mentions` What do you mean by tradition? That the Gemara had it by tradition? That it is our tradition to accept the Gemara? That we have received the Gemara through tradition? This seems like a confusing term (IMHO) that adds nothing. | `the serious transgression of "nivul peh"` That seems like quite an exaggeration. [It does not appear to be a Biblical or even Rabbinic prohibition](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/75346/8775). | Given that it does not appear to be a technical prohibition, but a general issue of conduct, it wont have technical parameters.

Comment: Malbim's commentary to Isaiah (9:16) indicates that term means overtly discussing sin. This seems very different from the idea of "foul language", and probably wouldn't include these terms (although they could of course be used for nivvul peh). However, from Shabbat (33a) and the discussion of "everyone knows why the bride is brought into the wedding canopy" it appears that it does not refer to speaking of sin, but to overt discussions of sexuality. | If that is the case, it seems unlikely that these would qualify. | If, however, the Talmud's point is just that its crude, these would qualify.

Comment: The title and the body ask two different things. The latter asks if the nivvul peh; apparently not a halakhic issue, discussed by Hazal includes "cursing". The former discusses a halakhic issue.

Comment: @DoubleAA I wouldn't say its a dupe. This question primarily asks whether it is nivvul peh. (not a halakhic issue, although the title confuses this point). The question you link to is a halakhic question.

Comment: @DoubleAA. It's not a dupe. Please read carefully before duping a question. By our tradition  I meant the words of chazal which I gave you the source for. Isn't divrei chazal part of our tradition? And you are wrong, there are technical parameters to this as seen in their words. And you are wrong - based on the terrible punishments enumerated there it is correct to say that it is a severe transgression.

Comment: Hi @MarkA. I do try and read carefully before duping a question. Your assertion that it's not a dupe doesn't change anything for me. Try explaining what the difference is.

Comment: @DoubleAA. I'm specifically asking if there is a difference between words that have sexual connotations and other words which refer to excrement, female dogs etc.

Comment: That does indeed appear to be one aspect of the question. A full answer to the linked question should address that.

Comment: @DoubleAA Is duping to another dupe a good idea? Seems likely to annoy readers.