# What is the Issur of Nivul Peh based on?

Tags: words, chilul-kidush-hashem

I am wondering what exactly the Issur of Nivul Peh is predicated on.

Is it:

1. That such words shouldn't be spoken from a person's mouth;                          or
2. That its a cause of chillul Hashem if someone sees a Jew saying something like that (and if someone speaks a different language it would only be a problem in the first part);     or
3. That the one it is directed to (if it was directed at someone) will be embarrassed;

Or is it a combination of them (or maybe there's a completely different reason, in which case, drop me a line)?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18222 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14257

Comment: Um, dupe? (And mine, too, I guess?)

Comment: See: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/75346/8775 which indicates that nivvul peh is not an actual prohibition. Rather, it is an outgrowth of standard norms of behaviour. Accordingly, nivvul peh presumably doesn't have technical definitions; rather, the point is to simply speak appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case of nivul peh that the Gemara gives is about talking about sensitive matters in an explicit and obscene way. In the words of the Gemara ([Shabbos 33a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=33&format=pdf)):

> הכל יודעין כלה למה נכנסה לחופה אלא כל המנבל פיו אפי' חותמין עליו גזר
>   דין של שבעים שנה לטובה הופכין עליו לרעה
>
> All know for what purpose a bride enters the bridal canopy, yet
>   against whomsoever who speaks obscenely [thereof], even if a sentence
>   of seventy years' happiness had been sealed for him, it is reversed
>   for evil.

This isn't simply saying 'bad words.' The rabbis taught ([Pesachim 3a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=3&format=pdf)) that it is proper for one to speak with clean language, but dirty words are not nivul peh per se - nivul peh is something said in context.

Therefore, to answer:

1) It isn't about specific words; it is about speaking a certain way about certain things.

2) There is no indication that this issue has anything to do with chillul Hashem. I think it is common sense that this is a simple issue of character refinement, and I also posited [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18228/1601) that that might be the biblical source for this idea.

3) Nivul peh is not classically something directed at someone.