# What is Nivul Peh and who decides what it is

Tags: words, hashkafah-philosophy

is Dam* or He** objectively considered curse words? what is the demarcator for curse words

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14257/halachot-of-lashon-naki-clean-speech

Comment: R' SR Hirsch in Horeb speaks about vulgar speech... I don't have my copy to hand, but I'll try to come back to this at home

Comment: There seem to be 2 questions here. Nivul Peh has already been answered - see deja-jew's reference. The permissibility of Dam* or He** (as you refer to them) is a separate question.

Comment: so i would appreciate an answer then.

Comment: @WanderingJew, please [edit] your title and body so that they both describe the same single, clear question.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18222/ and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18258/

Comment: I've closed this per @IsaacMoses's comment. It can be easily reopened once it's clear.