Rebbeim wearing wedding rings
Is there any reason why Rebbeim typically don't wear wedding rings? I have never seen any Rav wearing one and was wondering if there are any specific reasons for that. Are there any examples of famous or well respected Rabbis that do/did?

Do you see many non-Rebbeim wearing them? Do you see an easy-to-spot discrepancy between both groups?

See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28926/may-a-man-wear-a-wedding-band.   If we accept this that it is distasteful, I would assume Rabbis try to  not do distasteful things.

In my experience which is limited to me rings are fairly uncommon for men to wear both rabbis and laymen

I don't know of any men who wear rings, Rabbi or non-Rabbi, in both Hassidic and Yeshivish communities. My father mentioned one of his friends who wore one at work for actual specific reasons, but other than that it's just not a thing people do.

And once it's not part of an Orthodox wedding ceremony, and you're not routinely in a society that expects you to, why bother with it?

I heard that a student asked Rabbi M. Willig about wearing a wedding ring.  Rabbi Willig asked why he wanted to wear one.  The student said that at his job in accounting, non-Jewish women would assume a man without a wedding ring was single and express romantic interest.  Rabbi Willig said "In that case, the single men should also wear a wedding ring".  This was presumably somewhat tongue-in-cheek but if you follow that logic all the way, rabbis presumably don't have that problem at work, so it could even be an answer.

Men used to wear rings, as is clear from the Mishnah and Gemarra and Rishonim. I don't think Jewish men ever wore wedding rings until the practice was transplanted from non-Jewish society.

Gentile (Greek, Roman, Christian, and more) marriage implies mutuality - both parties must explicitly agree and either party can annul, but Jewish marriage doesn't - the woman is [passively] acquired by the man and only he can divorce. Similarly (Mishna Kiddushin 1-4), a slave or cattle bear "branding symbols" but not the master.

I would assume that sources on this will be rare to non-existent since there is no reason in Judaism for a man to wear a wedding ring.
It is true that Jewish men can wear rings, and might even have done so (see mishna in Masechta Shabbat discussing Men wearing a ring and many other sources in the Talmud) but that has nothing to do with this question.
The purpose of the wedding ring given to to the women in a Jewish marriage is in order to create a Kinyan Kiddushin - a transaction that makes the marriage valid. Only the man has the ability to be mekadesh the women and as such he gives the ring (btw, he could technically give anything else of monetary value more than a Peruta). So there is no point for the man to receive a ring.
I welcome you to also read the Wikipedia page, which brings some reasons for wedding rings in the gentile world , which do not apply in judaism.

Does the answer open the possibility that rabbis wear other jewelry items but not wedding bands?

There's also no reason in Judaism for a woman to wear a wedding ring.

You seem to confuse the rules and customs etc. about using a ring for kiddushin, with some sort of rule/minhag to wear it continuously from then on.

"The purpose of the wedding ring given to a woman..." it doesn't have to be a ring and a woman does not have to wear it at all. So the tradition of Jewish women wearing wedding rings is not Jewish in essence.
